# How Find Average Of Two Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays which have same entry count, for example:

```
var one = [0,20,30,40] ;
var two = [43,20,10,50] ;
```

I need to find similarity of these two array in percentage,
I tried something like that:

```
var avg = (one[0]-two[0] + one[1]-two[1] + one[2]-two[2] + one[3]-two[3]) / 4 ;
```

But results are not good,
How to calculate a proper average like this?

**Edit: *Please think of it as like similarity of two sounds data!***
Which means:

```
var one = [0,20,30,40] ;
var two = [0,40,60,80] ;
```

*The average of those would be 100%..*

Comment: What does "not good" mean? What you probably want to do is square each difference, sum them, divide by the number of entries, then take the square root of that. (If you really want a percentage, so it's out of 100, things get more complex. Tell us what you *really* want.)

Comment: What exactly do you want? A new array with 4 elements, each of them being the average of the 2 original arrays' elements at that position? Or just 1 number that's the average of both arrays?

Comment: What average are you trying to find? If you want the avg of all numbers in both arrays, add them all up and divide by 8. If you want to get the avg of both arrays at a certain place add the values at that place in both arrays and divide by 2. It's hard to answer if it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Results are either correct or incorrect. If the results are incorrect, what would you expect as correct result?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Please think of it as like similarity of two sounds data

Comment: @Kevin could you illustrate what you mean in js?

Comment: I don't follow. Why would the average of those last two arrays be 100%? Can you show how you got that? I would assume 100% would mean the arrays were identical, and those arrays are different. (Is it that the second array is 100% greater than the first at each point? If so, what if all values are zero?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why not? Those two arrays have same ratio, but different volume. All we need is only maximalize them, It would be very easy for that example.

Comment: @Digerkam: Okay, then you need to scale each array before you compare them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want just one number that's the average of both arrays combined, try this:

```
var one = [0,20,30,40];
var two = [43,20,10,50];
var i, j;
var average = 0;

for(i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    average += one[i];
}
for(j = 0; j < two.length; j++){ // (two arrays for flexibility.)
    average += two[j];
}
console.log(average /= (i+j));
// 26.625
```

If you want the average of the arrays, at the specific indexes, try this:

```
var one = [0,20,30,40];
var two = [43,20,10,50];
var i;
var average = [];

for(i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    average.push((one[i] + two[i]) / 2);
}

console.log(average);
// [21.5, 20, 20, 45]
```

**Edit:**

From what I can see of your edit, you want the average percentage that's added to `one`, to get `two`. This should work:

```
var i, n = 0;
var average = 0;

var one = [0,20,30,40] ;
var two = [0,60,70,120] ;

for(i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    if(one[i] != 0){
        average += two[i] / one[i];
        n++;
    }
}
average = (average / n - 1)*100;
```

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score -2):

```
var one = [0,20,30,40];
var two = [43,20,10,50];
var temp=one.concat(two)
var sum=0 , average=0;
for (i=0; i<temp.length;i++){
sum+=temp[i];
} 
avg=sum/i
document.write(sum);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(avg);
```

This is a simple code.let me know whether this is what you ask for.

Comment: `document.write` to output values? At least use `alert()`, or better yet, `console.log()`.

Comment: document.write   i just added that to show him easily whether the answer is getting correctly or not.   thanks for your comments.